# how to make the marker like google in python plotly express

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-maps, plotly, plotly-express

I have to change the marker default of the plotly express to the marker like google maps
can you give me the suggestion of code

I already try this code :
def map():

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        hover_name=df['kabko'],
                        hover_data=['Jumlah'],
                        lon=df['long'],
                        lat=df['lat'],
                        zoom=5,
                        # size=df['Jumlah'],
                        width=1200,
                        height=900,
                        title="Pesebaran Covid-19 di Indonesia")
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=15))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style='open-street-map')
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 50, "l": 0, "b": 10})
fig.show()
fig.scatter()
```

And the result is :

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your Google marker refers to, but you can use symbols for graph object markers. Not all of the ones on the [following site](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) can be used, but I have specified the markers in this list. Unfortunately, I could not change the color. I used a custom symbol in the [Multiple Markers](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers) and [Set Marker Symbols](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#set-marker-symbols).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=['38.91427','38.91538','38.91458',
             '38.92239','38.93222','38.90842',
             '38.91931','38.93260','38.91368',
             '38.88516','38.921894','38.93206',
             '38.91275'],
        lon=['-77.02827','-77.02013','-77.03155',
             '-77.04227','-77.02854','-77.02419',
             '-77.02518','-77.03304','-77.04509',
             '-76.99656','-77.042438','-77.02821',
             '-77.01239'],
        mode='markers+text',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=12,
            symbol='marker',
        ),
        text=["The coffee bar","Bistro Bohem","Black Cat",
             "Snap","Columbia Heights Coffee","Azi's Cafe",
             "Blind Dog Cafe","Le Caprice","Filter",
             "Peregrine","Tryst","The Coupe",
             "Big Bear Cafe"],
    textposition = "bottom right"
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    height=450,
    width=900,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style='basic',
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=38.92,
            lon=-77.04
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=12
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This graph uses the [Mapbox API](https://www.mapbox.com/studio), which can be obtained free of charge.

Comment: I can't access the mapbox api key because I don't have the account, can I borrow your mapbox api key

Comment: I cannot lend you my API key. Please select a new account under login in the comments, and if you pass the authentication, you will have your own page, where you will be issued an API key. It is very easy.